# How do I run a .one() jQuery only once, even when there are multiple selectors in that

Tags: jquery

```
$('.div1, .div2').one(
  'click',
  function() {
    // #code here
});
```

So basically when I click on `.div1`, the #code here should get executed. But `.div2` is still clickable. I don't want `.div2` to be clickable. So basically I want `.div1` || `.div2`.

Can you please tell me any solutions for this?

Comment: So which one is it: `But .div2 is still clickable. I don't want .div2 to be clickable.` those are opposites.

Comment: @ErikPhilips the OP. wants _both_ elements to respond, but once either element has responded neither should respond again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
function myFunction(){
  console.log('clicked once');
  document.querySelector('.one').removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
  document.querySelector('.two').removeEventListener('click', myFunction);
}
//adding click event to button
document.querySelector('.one').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
document.querySelector('.two').addEventListener('click', myFunction);

});
```

```html
You use Javascript default `removeEventListener` to remove it from selector<br/>
<button class="one" type="button">One</button>
<button class="two" type="button">Two</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to have a solution with jQuery, here it is:

```js
let divs=$('.one, .two').one('click',
  function(){console.log('Click on button '+this.className);
  divs.off('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
You use Javascript default `removeEventListener` to remove it from selector<br/>
<button class="one" type="button">One</button>
<button class="two" type="button">Two</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [delegated event handler](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) by registering the (one-off) handler on a common parent element, and then using the sub-selector to pick the elements that may match:

```
$('body').one('click', '.div1, .div2', ...);
```

Since the event handler is technically only registered on one element, the `.one` logic ensures that the event only fires once regardless of which child element is clicked.

```js
$('body').one('click', '.div1, .div2', function() {
  console.log(this.className);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="div1" type="button">One</button>
<button class="div2" type="button">Two</button>
```